# Sort Collection by Array Count (MongoDB)

Tags: arrays, mongodb

So I want to sort the collection in descending order by array count. In my current code I have "UpVote: -1" which would usually work but with an array it seems to sort the collection by the highest number or longest length of a char INSIDE the array, what I want is for it to sort by the array count itself.

**CRUD Service class**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetPopular<T>(string collectionName)
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
        return await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Sort("{UpVote: -1}").ToListAsync();
    }
```

This doesn't sort the collection by array count like I assumed it would, instead it sorts the collection by highest int or longest string inside the UpVote array.

**Collection In Question**

[image: Screenshot of collection]

As of right now the collection will be sorted in descending order with the second record at the top since it has the highest number out of all of them. What I'm trying to do however as stated above is sort by array count so it should be the third record ontop, followed by the first record then lastly the second.

Answer (score 0):

You could use aggregate pipeline stages `$project` and `$sort` stages. [Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5IpJW0ciREg), Mongo shell query as follows

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      upvote_count: {
        $size: {
          "$ifNull": [
            "$upvote",
            []
          ]
        }
      },
      key: 1,
      upvote: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "upvote_count": -1
    }
  }
])
```